# Oomph preference recorder settings

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I want to set Maven -> Installations to a particular path for all my workspaces in eclipse. 
My user.setup file has following entry too.

```
<setupTask
    xsi:type="setup:CompoundTask"
    name="org.eclipse.m2e.core">
  <setupTask
      xsi:type="setup:PreferenceTask"
      key="/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.runtimesNodes/apache-maven-3.2.5/location"
      value="C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5"/>
  <setupTask
      xsi:type="setup:PreferenceTask"
      key="/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.runtimesNodes/apache-maven-3.2.5/type"
      value="EXTERNAL"/>
</setupTask>
```

But it didn't get reflected in all workspace on starting the eclipse. I am using Eclipse neon. Can anybody suggest where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check *Eclipse > Preferences > Oomph > Setup Tasks > Skip automatic task execution at startup time*.

I read that if this is disabled, Eclipse won't update to changed `.setup`. But I can't tell if this is the case to `user.setup` as well...